# Team City Jobs to update only a certain folder from Git?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am new to TeamCity and have a use case where there are multiple changes in the repository but I only want to update a certain folder on my server via team city job. For example, I have some changes in the config folder inside the project and I would only like to update that particular folder and ignore the rest.

Is it possible to do that? If so how would be the right way to go about it?

PS : I am aware that config should have been done more on a environment basis but I don't have authority to change the existing architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just found a solution for this by extracting the tar from git to a different folder, removing my current folder I needed to change from existing folder and copying the folder from the newly extracted tar.

## Create tar at teamcity

tar -czf /tmp/application.tar.gz .

## remove folder

ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  server "rm ~/application/server/config -R -f && rm ~/application/server/modules/sampling/assets/ -R -f && rm -R -f ~/application_new/"

## Copy tar and untar

ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  server "mkdir ~/application_new/ && tar -C ~/application_new/ -xz -f-" < /tmp/application.tar.gz

## run build

ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  server "cp -avr ~/application_new/server/config ~/application/server/ && cp -avr ~/application_new/server/modules/sampling/assets/ ~/application/server/modules/sampling/"

## stop process in pm2

ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  server "pm2 delete application"

## Set NODE_ENV and Start Nodejs

ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  server "cd application && export NODE_ENV=dev && export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 && pm2 start process.json"